# Flag considered invalid and then related post is closed

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag deemed Invalid, but question closed for the same reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/flag-deemed-invalid-but-question-closed-for-the-same-reason)

Some time ago, I've flagged this post: [I want to start Java Stand alone(Swing) application without dos prompt to open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076972/i-want-to-start-java-stand-aloneswing-application-without-dos-prompt-to-open) with "very low quality" flag. My flag was considered Invalid and then, some time later I see this post closed because it's "closed as not a real question".

"Very low quality" stands for "This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed".

Why is my flag considered invalid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flag deemed Invalid, but question closed for the same reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/flag-deemed-invalid-but-question-closed-for-the-same-reason), [Flag marked invalid even though question was closed for same reason: can I challenge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98347/flag-marked-invalid-even-though-question-was-closed-for-same-reason-can-i-challe), [Why was my flag invalid when the requested action was taken?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98653/why-was-my-flag-invalid-when-the-requested-action-was-taken)

Comment: @loki, that's because the community and the moderators do not operate as a hive mind (yet). The moderator disagreed with you, but the community agreed with you in the end.

Comment: Also potentially relevant, considering that you flagged as "very low quality": [Flagged a question, I got an Invalid and the question got closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98206/flagged-a-question-i-got-an-invalid-and-the-question-got-closed)

Comment: We get questions like this all the time, all of which boil down to "why are moderators acting like human beings rather than mindless automatons?"  Guess what--we're humans, and we screw up sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, clearly because you weren't holding your mouth right when you submitted that flag. Or maybe this one is because the moon was in the wrong phase.

Or more likely, because the flag was processed by a moderator, who marked it as invalid, but the question was closed by a consensus of 5 users with 3k+ reputation ([close vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)).

Only moderators have the ability to mark flags as valid or invalid, so this happens fairly often. The closing was not connected to your flag; it was merely a coincidence.