# Flag marked as invalid for the exact reason the question was closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark flags as valid if question is subsequently closed for the exact reason (eg not a real question) as the original flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102609/mark-flags-as-valid-if-question-is-subsequently-closed-for-the-exact-reason-eg-n)

I've seen the other questions here about questions being closed, and people being mad that their flags were marked as invalid. But those seem to be on "flag as not a real question", or it was vote-closed by the community.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149087/query-is-adding-records-twice) was closed **by a moderator** as exact duplicate, which is what I had flagged it for prior to closing.

Surely if a moderator deems the post to be an exact duplicate, my flag is actually valid? I'd not be upset with a "disputed" marking, since marking it as "invalid" directly conflicts with what the moderator who closed the question thinks, and therefore the flag would be under dispute.

EDIT: I propose that questions which are closed by a moderator for a particular reason, automatically mark flags for that given reason as "Valid".

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Mark flags as valid if question is subsequently closed for the exact reason (eg not a real question) as the original flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102609).

Comment: @Hendrik Not a dupe, that one regards a question marked as "Not a real question", which differs significantly from "exact duplicate" as "not a real question" is far more subjective.

Comment: This happens apparently because we're not all linked to cybernetic perfection like the Borg collective.

Comment: No doubt, but it raises the point that something needs to be done to prevent it from happening

Comment: @Cyclone: Naturally. Cybernetic implants, of course; a suggestion for branded ones could be [made here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want).

Comment: @Cyclone: It says "eg" in the title of that question, so it's not only about "Not a real question". And our short discussion shows that "exact duplicate" is also subjective `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: The question itself focused on that one type of flag however, and "exact duplicate" is far less subjective than "not a real question". It's easy to see when a questions content is close to that of another question, but hard to tell if it isn't really a question without being an expert on the subject, as it was decided in that question you linked to.

Comment: @Cyclone Someone else commented on *that* question pointing to *another* question about flagging as Very Low Quality.  It doesn't matter why you flagged it; your flag was valid, yet marked as invalid.  That's the only point under consideration, the degree of subjectivity is irrelevant.  All 3 of these questions are the same.

Comment: Oh look, another one of *these* questions.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your edit:

> I propose that questions which are closed by a moderator for a particular reason, automatically mark flags for that given reason as "Valid".

This is already the case, but only for currently active flags.  If a moderator manually marks your flag as "invalid" then that's the final result of your flag, regardless of whether the community, another moderator, or *the same* moderator *later* closes the question for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sometimes happens to me also. It's probably the wrong button on in the moderator's tools; however, I don't think you can do much about this.

Comment: Surely there could be an auto "valid" mark if a question is closed for the exact same reason you flagged?

Comment: I think yes it could, good idea

Comment: Edited the question to include that suggestion